# Access group levels in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to obtain the group levels of a grouped object in `dplyr`. This is of course equal to the grouping variable(s) right after grouping. 
Grouped variables cannot be modified, but they can be expanded. Take the following example:

```
some_df <- data_frame(gr    = LETTERS[1:2], 
                      value = c(3,4))

add_a_row <- function(x) {
  row <- data_frame(gr = NA, value = NA)
  if (runif(1) < 0.5) {
    rbind(x, row)
  } else {
    rbind(row, x)
  }
}

some_df %>% group_by(gr) %>% 
  do(add_a_row(.)) %>% 
  do( )
```

So to each group an empty row is added, either as the first or as the last line. In the final `do` I would like to set 'gr' to its group level. Is there a way to access the group levels so the final `do` can be:

```
 do(mutate(., gr = gr_level))
```

(The above is just an example of a use case for clarity. Question is how to access the group levels, not how to solve the small problem above).

Comment: Could you show the expected output?

Comment: Have a look at `?group_indices`. However, in your example you are modifying the grouping variable to NA, thereby adding an additional group.

Comment: Perfect, that was what I was looking for, but couldn't find. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

We can change the function slightly by changing the `NA` to `x$gr` in the `row` creation

```
add_a_row <- function(x) {
    row <- data_frame(gr = x$gr, value = NA)
     if (runif(1) < 0.5) {
      rbind(x, row)
     } else {
     rbind(row, x)
   }
 }

some_df %>%
     group_by(gr) %>% 
     do(add_a_row(.))
#    gr value
#    <chr> <dbl>
#1     A    NA
#2     A     3
#3     B    NA
#4     B     4
```

-

Comment: Sure, that's a way to do it, but I am not looking to solve this specific problem. I want to know if it is possible to extract the group levels...

Comment: @Edwin I am not completely sure what you want.  That is why I commented under your question.  If it is to extract then `some_df %>% group_by(gr) %>%  do(add_a_row(.)) %>% .$gr %>% na.omit` based on your function

Comment: I was thus looking for the `group_indices` function. Thanks anyway

Comment: For the record, I did not down vote. However, as I wrote in the post. I was looking for a way to access the group levels and the example posted was just a use case in which it could be used. Thanks to konvas and your answer I now learned I see that this is not the way to solve this type of problems, since it creates and extra category of NA.

Comment: @Edwin Yes, the problem with your approach was that it shows NA as one of the values in the group.  Yes, you can access the group levels with group_indices function.  But, without an expected output, I don't know whether you wanted just the levels or the dataset with the group or not